# How to use ftp.simple in VSCode

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-code, error-log

I have installed ftp.simple, watched the YouTube video, created a SFTP config for a remote server in the ftp-simple-temp-json, and run the command: Open the file directly from FTP server, among others.  Nothing happens -- no messages as sent in the video.  Any ideas about what is going wrong?  Is there a log file that I can look at?  Thanks, Sue.

Comment: I found a similar issue that was asked in Nov'17, see "Visual code studio ftp-simple doesn't work"  He had the same problem: Nothing happens. Based on the comments, I can say 1) I'm using SFTP, not FTP, 2)  I tried a site with a UserID and Password, and one with a certificate key, 3) I can SSH into the server from the command line, 4) I'm on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 11):

after installing ftp-simple from extensions

1- check your internet connection.

2- restart VS CODE.

3- **cmd** + **shift** + **p** --> type: **ftp-simple:Config** --> Enter

4- you can see `ftp-simple-temp.json` file change it like so

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sample-Name",
        "host": "Sample-Host",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "ftp",
        "username": "Your FTP USERNAME",
        "password": "Your FTP PASSWORD",
        "path": "/",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true
    }
]
```

---> save then hit enter.

5- a little bar at the top of the window shows up with "Sample-Name" given above --> hit enter

6- wait a moment (depending on your internet connection speed)
then another little bar pops up with a directory of your FTP server and just hit enter to see the entire project folder.

you should be fine...

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "a little bar at the top of the window"? After I edit the config file and hit Save, I don't see anything on the interface change. I do not see "a little bar at the top of the window." Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @drew-chapin if little bar don't show up for u i don't know maybe it's for Earlier versions of VSCODE or maybe you should check your object and your connection cause that little bar depend on it.
it just take the object and make a connection with information that you provide.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Is there a logger where to check what's going on?

Comment: @drew-chapin it's like a popup when you hit cmd+shift+p

Comment: If your doing react builds, how do you configure ftp-simple source to be the project/build folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the logs to see if an error occurred.

```
%appdata%/Code/logs/[Date]/renderer1.log
```

I found the error I had using this file.

My versions:

- VSCode 1.27.2 (64 bits)
- ftp-simple 0.6.7

Answer (score 1):

1. Press F1, in the input type ftp-simple
2. Click on the **ftp-simple:Config** then a file will be open
3. fill the file with true information like below and save it:

```
    {
        "name": "any given name",
        "host": "given ftp address",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "ftp",
        "username": "given username",
        "password": "given password",
        "path": "/",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true
    }
```

4. Press F1 again and type ftp-simple and click on **ftp-simple:Open** then your chosen name in a little bar will be show up on top
5. click on chosen name on the top bar and go to directory you want
6. if after doing this nothing happened or in the 4th step nothing show up to you then go to log file directory: a address like below

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs

and find out what is the problem.

Comment: Do you know where I can change what directory on my local machine this saves to when I download files? I would rather it be something other than "\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\ftp-simple\remote-workspace-temp\a1487f600695f93a54550b9d27e45c21\public_html"

Comment: As far as I know and searched, it is the default address and we can't change the directory of saving remote server file in our local machine using ftp.simple. you can send a message and ask from ftp.simple support team to guide you or probably put that option in newer versions of VSCode.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The part with pressing F1 again and going to Open is what all others are missing.