# How to download a remote file using ftp-simple in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I download a file from a remote server using ftp-simple? I'm using VSCode. I'm open to recommendations on sftp extensions that work with VSCode. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to that server...it shouldn't be a problem if you have the credentials to enter.

Comment: The issue isn't access to the server. I can upload fine. But I'm wondering how can I download a certain file from the server to my local machine. Just like any other GUI ftp program. Not downloading the entire site, but single files in case my local file is out of synch with the remote file and I want to overwrite it with the remote version.

Comment: You can try this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp

Answer (score 0):

First you have to connect FTP server using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852255/7175318)  then open your looking file and save it to your computer. or after connecting to FTP server, you can refer to your file's location using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54865045/7175318)  and find your target file.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to connect FTP server using this then open your looking file and save it to your computer. or after connecting to FTP server, you can refer to your file's location using this and find your target file.