# How to get FTP-Simple working in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently opted to start using Visual Studio Code. I want to connect to a remote server and edit files directly on the server. FTP-Simple seems like a great solution. But I am having a hard time understanding some basics about the program.

If I make a connection to a server, does FTP-Simple download *all* the actual files to my hard drive?

Also, I was able to make a connection, but in one of the directories there should be a sub-directory and it's missing. What am I doing wrong?

Can someone point me to some good documentation for this extension such as video(s), etc.

Answer (score 0):

> If I make a connection to a server, does FTP-Simple download all the
>   actual files to my hard drive?

Yes, It download all to your hard drive. you can find an address like below:

 `C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\ftp-simple\remote-workspace-temp\cbc1ad9ed60f12ec861052806d7833db\httpdocs`

for opening a directory in VSCode you can press F1 type ftp-config then click **ftp-config:Open**
 and click on target directory you want to open for more information use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217994/how-to-use-ftp-simple-in-vscode/54852255#54852255)

Answer (score 0):

2 years later and I'm having the same problem. I have already uninstalled ftp simple as well as VSC with no effect.

The plugin just doesn't download all the files on the FTP. It worked the first time I installed it for 2-3 weeks and then suddenly stopped being in sync with the FTP server.

There is a folder called "`code`" on mac in `Library/Application Support` where most of VSC data is saved, but deleting this didn't have an effect either. Perhaps it works for someone else, as this is apparently necessary to fully deinstall VSC.

I'd pay for good plugin that just allows to work remotely on ftp files!!