# What is "command 'ftp-config' not found" error in visual studio code (VSCode) ftp-simple

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp

I am trying to connect ftp server and **edit** & **save** my files on the remote server using ftp-simple but after updating VSCode recently, I receive the error:

> **command 'ftp-config not found**

, while I did not change any config file, and also I tried to reinstall but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for previous answers.if after checking the existence of `ftp-simple-temp.json`,the problem did not solve.

Check the existence of `ftp-simple.json` in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` or an address like that. If there is not such this file, create an empty file by the name of `ftp-simple.json` and Disable/Enable Or Uninstall/Install the ftp-simple module and if there is new update do it.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade extension or install (0.6.9) then it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. go to "C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Code\User",  open if exist or create new file by name

> ftp-simple-temp.json

and put below code in it and fill with you true ftp connection information:

```
[
 {
  "name": "your choosen name",
  "host": "ftp host address",
  "port": 21,
  "type": "ftp",
  "username": "ftp username",
  "password": "The ftp password",
  "path": "/",
  "autosave": true,
  "confirm": true
 }
]
```

save file and start over the VSCode then try to connect ftp according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217994/how-to-use-ftp-simple-in-vscode) link.